# Laravel5 eager loading not working

Tags: php, laravel-5, eager-loading

I have the following models

```
class ParentModel extends Model
{
  public function children()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Model\Student', 'parent_id');
  }
}

class Student extends Model
{

}
```

When I use `ParentModel::find(1)->children`, it gives the correct result. 
But when I use `ParentModel::with('children')->find(1)`, the result array contains a `children` key with value as empty array.

Answer (score 0):

you can try the following as i'm not sure that `with` method will work along side with `find`:

```
ParentModel::with('children')->where(array('ParentModel_pmk_id' => 1))->get();
```